# Unfortunately has stopped - android

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I was successfully compiled when I was run, but I faced into this message when I was excute application. 'Unfortunately has stopped'

Now I'm trying to use V7-appcompat that update couple of days ago.
This is my source code.

main activity

```
package com.exasmple.oh;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);


    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

}
```

menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:title="Menu"
    yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    yourapp:showAsAction="always" />

<item
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:title="Share"
        yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
        yourapp:showAsAction="always" />


</menu>
```

and I only updates build.gradle this.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
```

and also import library \\

This isn't any error before run, but it does after run.

This is my logcat

```
07-23 20:40:11.801
784-784/com.android.exchange E/StrictMode: null
android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked
ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d3a3a0 that was
originally bound here
at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
 at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
    at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
    at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
    at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-23 20:40:11.811      303-546/system_process W/ActivityManager: Unbind failed: could not find
 connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40e91230
```

Comment: 'Unfortunately has stopped' it is the way Android tells you that you have a unhandled exception. Connect the debugger and see which exception is and which line of code throws it

Comment: Yes, in addition to that, paste the `LogCat` too, it could give us a clue.

Comment: well Yes!
hmm.....now I add my logcat.
not just above, after I was updating my build.gradle to use appcompat, I just changed my mainActivity.java extends ActionBarActivity, It happens too.